# Getting error while running query on hive over tez

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, apache-tez

Getting error while running query on hive over tez. As per logs, hive is failing while copying  `tez jars` to a `hdfs` location on start of `tez session`.Below is the complete log obtained from hive `log` file :

```
2015-06-19 01:23:52,289 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(852)) - Query ID = saurabh_20150619012323_f52f1d6c-2adb-4edc-8ba4-b64d7d898325
2015-06-19 01:23:52,289 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(852)) - Total jobs = 1
2015-06-19 01:23:52,289 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit start=1434657232288 end=1434657232289 duration=1 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-19 01:23:52,290 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=runTasks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-19 01:23:52,290 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=task.TEZ.Stage-1 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-19 01:23:52,302 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(852)) - Launching Job 1 out of 1
2015-06-19 01:23:52,302 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:launchTask(1630)) - Starting task [Stage-1:MAPRED] in parallel
2015-06-19 01:23:52,312 INFO  [Thread-21]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(488)) - No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
2015-06-19 01:23:52,314 INFO  [Thread-21]: tez.TezSessionPoolManager (TezSessionPoolManager.java:getSession(125)) - QueueName: null nonDefaultUser: true defaultQueuePool: null blockingQueueLength: -1
2015-06-19 01:23:52,315 INFO  [Thread-21]: tez.TezSessionPoolManager (TezSessionPoolManager.java:getNewSessionState(154)) - Created a new session for queue: null session id: 85d83746-a48e-419e-a7ca-8c98faf173ea
2015-06-19 01:23:52,380 INFO  [Thread-21]: Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1049)) - mapred.committer.job.setup.cleanup.needed is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.committer.setup.cleanup.needed
2015-06-19 01:23:52,412 INFO  [Thread-21]: ql.Context (Context.java:getMRScratchDir(328)) - New scratch dir is hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive/saurabh/e5a701ae-242d-488f-beec-cf18878becdc/hive_2015-06-19_01-23-49_794_2167174123575230985-2
2015-06-19 01:23:52,420 INFO  [Thread-21]: exec.Task (TezTask.java:updateSession(233)) - Tez session hasn't been created yet. Opening session
2015-06-19 01:23:52,420 INFO  [Thread-21]: tez.TezSessionState (TezSessionState.java:open(142)) - User of session id 85d83746-a48e-419e-a7ca-8c98faf173ea is saurabh
2015-06-19 01:23:52,433 INFO  [Thread-21]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:localizeResource(950)) - Localizing resource because it does not exist: file:/usr/lib/tez/* to dest: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive/saurabh/_tez_session_dir/85d83746-a48e-419e-a7ca-8c98faf173ea/*
2015-06-19 01:23:52,433 INFO  [Thread-21]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:localizeResource(954)) - Looks like another thread is writing the same file will wait.
2015-06-19 01:23:52,433 INFO  [Thread-21]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:localizeResource(961)) - Number of wait attempts: 5. Wait interval: 5000
2015-06-19 01:24:17,449 ERROR [Thread-21]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:localizeResource(977)) - Could not find the jar that was being uploaded
2015-06-19 01:24:17,451 ERROR [Thread-21]: exec.Task (TezTask.java:execute(184)) - Failed to execute tez graph.
java.io.IOException: Previous writer likely failed to write hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive/saurabh/_tez_session_dir/85d83746-a48e-419e-a7ca-8c98faf173ea/*. Failing because I am unlikely to write too.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DagUtils.localizeResource(DagUtils.java:978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DagUtils.addTempResources(DagUtils.java:859)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DagUtils.localizeTempFilesFromConf(DagUtils.java:802)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.refreshLocalResourcesFromConf(TezSessionState.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask.updateSession(TezTask.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask.execute(TezTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:75)
2015-06-19 01:24:18,329 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(861)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
2015-06-19 01:24:18,329 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1434657232288 end=1434657258329 duration=26041 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-19 01:24:18,329 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-19 01:24:18,329 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1434657258329 end=1434657258329 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-19 01:24:18,333 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-41]: operation.Operation (SQLOperation.java:run(200)) - Error running hive query: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:315)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:147)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$100(SQLOperation.java:70)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1$1.run(SQLOperation.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1.run(SQLOperation.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-06-19 01:24:18,342 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: exec.ListSinkOperator (Operator.java:close(595)) - 40 finished. closing... 
2015-06-19 01:24:18,343 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: exec.ListSinkOperator (Operator.java:close(613)) - 40 Close done
2015-06-19 01:24:18,393 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-19 01:24:18,394 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1434657258393 end=1434657258394 duration=1 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
```

Comment: completely stuck on this  ...checked source code on grepcode..unable to understand why jars are getting copied on open of tez session ...in which ioexception is coming ..may due to some file permission...even tried as superuser ..no luck  ..                                                                                 Now not able to switch back to mr engine ...giving hell of exception in hive log

Comment: After relooking at source code and below link .....it looks like a file name with * is creating the problem ...but checked the folder contains and was unable to find any file with * ....just wondering how a path with * is getting formed ..... [link mentioned ]http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201411.mbox/%3C546FEEA1.3080004@apache.org%3E

Comment: same issue no solution until now...